# Jenkins: how to pass Git credentials in parameterized job?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, credentials

We have one Git Bitbacket repository with many forks. I want to create a job that allows to run code from any of these forks via parameterized job.
My usercase is: somebody click on Build with parameters, selects his/her repository fork and branch, selects credentials (or add new and select) and then start job. Jenkins should get code from his/her fork with his/her credentials.

I use Git plugin and Credential plugin.
[I moved repository url and branch to parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVGkz.png).
Also, I added necessary credentials to Credentials plugin. [Then I created Credentials parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65yb6.png).

But I cannot make Git getting this parameters. I always get "Authentication failed" error.
How can I bind selected credentials to Git plugin? What I should select in Credentials field to make Git get this creds from job parameters? Or I should do something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether whether it's possible to parameterise Git credentials at all. Even though you could do that, this could potentially expose a **security vulnerability** for the Git accounts if your Jenkins instance isn't **SSL** protected (uses **HTTPS** protocol rather than plain **HTTP**).

> **Alternative approach:**

When you refer to multiple forks, I assume they are just a number of feature branches of the main master one that will eventually be merged with the master.

**I think you can also achieve your goal with a single Jenkins job configured to build any branch in a designated Git repository.** You will need to configure the Git Plugin with a single user, either one of your team members or create a dedicated one, exclusively for the Jenkins builds. Then, in the plugin configuration, you need to define some of the properties as follows:

- Repositories -> Name: origin
- Repositories -> Refspec: leave blank
- **Branches to build**: **  *(these two asterisks is the key one)*

Now, any push to any branch within your configured Git repository will be picked up by Jenkins provided you have configured `Web Hooks` in the repository for Jenkins notification.

**The advantage of this approach is that the development and build cycle is fully automated.** You can also add automated email notifications.

Note this answer is based on Jenkins version 1.6xx.